# 'torchmetrics' does not work with PyTorchLightning

Tags: python-3.x, metrics, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to understand how to use [torchmetrics](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/lightning.html) with PyTorch Lightning.

But, I got a same output with Accuracy, F1-score, Precision, etc.

**This is the code.**

```html
metric_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()
metric_f1 = torchmetrics.F1()
metric_pre = torchmetrics.Precision()
metric_rec = torchmetrics.Recall()

n_batches = 3
for i in range(n_batches):
    # simulate a classification problem
    preds = torch.randn(10, 5).softmax(dim=-1)
    target = torch.randint(5, (10,))

    acc = metric_acc(preds, target)
    f1 = metric_f1(preds, target)
    pre = metric_pre(preds, target)
    rec = metric_rec(preds, target)
    print(f"Accuracy on batch {i}: {acc}")
    print(f"F1 score on batch {i}: {f1}")
    print(f"pre score on batch {i}: {pre}")
    print(f"rec score on batch {i}: {rec}")
    print('-' * 20)


acc = metric_acc.compute()
f1 = metric_f1.compute()
pre = metric_pre.compute()
rec = metric_rec.compute()
print(f"Accuracy on all data: {acc}")
print(f"f1 score on all data: {f1}")
print(f"pre score on all data: {pre}")
print(f"rec score on all data: {rec}")
```

**Result is here.**

```html
Accuracy on batch 0: 0.10000000149011612
F1 score on batch 0: 0.10000000894069672
pre score on batch 0: 0.10000000149011612
rec score on batch 0: 0.10000000149011612
--------------------
Accuracy on batch 1: 0.30000001192092896
F1 score on batch 1: 0.30000001192092896
pre score on batch 1: 0.30000001192092896
rec score on batch 1: 0.30000001192092896
--------------------
Accuracy on batch 2: 0.4000000059604645
F1 score on batch 2: 0.40000003576278687
pre score on batch 2: 0.4000000059604645
rec score on batch 2: 0.4000000059604645
--------------------
Accuracy on all data: 0.2666666805744171
f1 score on all data: 0.2666666805744171
pre score on all data: 0.2666666805744171
rec score on all data: 0.2666666805744171

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I got the same result when I used it with PyTorchLightning, so I try it with simple code and got the same thing.
If you know the problem or the solution, please let me know.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you find what the issue was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that for multi class classification if you are using F1, Precision, ACC and Recall with micro (the default )these are [equivalent metrics](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/metrics/issues/298) and recommending you should use macro

```
metric_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy(average='macro')
metric_f1 = torchmetrics.F1(average='macro')
metric_pre = torchmetrics.Precision(average='macro')
metric_rec = torchmetrics.Recall(average='macro')
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!!! Thanks to you, I can ideally score!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are looking for this [simple example](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/lightning.html#logging-torchmetrics) of how to use TorchMetrics for logging your training progress with PytorchLightning. Otherwise, could you more elaborate on your use-case, ideally add your application example?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! I can learn a lot from the code you game me!!<(_ _)>